# Problemas com acentuação no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Não estou conseguindo salvar frases ou palavras com caracteres especiais ( ' & " ).
Meu banco esta assim:

```
ALTER DATABASE `bancodedados` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Todos os campos em utf8 e utf8_general_ci certinho...
Simplesmente não salva o registro inteiro, mas se eu removo os caracteres especiais do campo (que não é o caso), ele salva o registro inteiro!

Estou usando PHP+MySQL... Em PHP utilizo o header:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Por que os dados vem de uma requisição JSON! Já tentei com "utf8_decode()" também e nada!

Query:

```
$matriz = json_decode ( json_encode ($_POST['dados']), true);        
$itens = $matriz['results'];

    foreach ($itens as $e ){
       $name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/", "", strtr($e["name"], "áàãâéêíóôõúüçñÁÀÃÂÉÊÍÓÔÕÚÜÇÑ ", "aaaaeeiooouucnAAAAEEIOOOUUCN "));
       $SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhes_empresa (place_id, nome_empresa, latitude, longitude, icone, scope, aberto_agora, reference, vicinity, harario_func_dias, foto_referencia, foto_height, foto_width, foto_atribuicoes, aberto_agora_periodos)VALUES('".utf8_decode($e["place_id"])."', '".$name."', '".$_POST['latitude']."', '".$_POST['longitude']."', '".utf8_decode($e["icon"])."', '', '', '".utf8_decode($e["reference"])."', '".utf8_decode($e["vicinity"])."', '', '', '', '', '', '');";                
       $query = mysqli_query($serve, $SQL); or die("erro".mysqli_error());
    }
```

Retorno JSON (parte):

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.870775,
               "lng" : 151.199025
            }
         },
         "icon" : "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/travel_agent-71.png",
         "id" : "21a0b251c9b8392186142c798263e289fe45b4aa",
         "name" : "Rhythmboat Cruises",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 270,
               "html_attributions" : [],
               "photo_reference" : "CnRnAAAAF-LjFR1ZV93eawe1cU_3QNMCNmaGkowY7CnOf-kcNmPhNnPEG9W979jOuJJ1sGr75rhD5hqKzjD8vbMbSsRnq_Ni3ZIGfY6hKWmsOf3qHKJInkm4h55lzvLAXJVc-Rr4kI9O1tmIblblUpg2oqoq8RIQRMQJhFsTr5s9haxQ07EQHxoUO0ICubVFGYfJiMUPor1GnIWb5i8",
               "width" : 519
            }
         ],
```

Comment: Você precisa postar mais partes do seu código, poste a query que faz a inserção dos dados no banco.

Comment: editei o post!!!

Comment: Desconfio que os caracteres estão quebrando a query, eles precisam ser escapados. faça um teste, remova o '&' e faça um tratamento do código com addslashes,  $dado = addslashes($_POST['dadorecebido']) para escapar as aspas.

Comment: Acho que deveria ser `utf8_encode()` e não `utf8_decode()`

Comment: Cara, e pior que é uma matriz em json complicada da API do Google Places, vou postar um pedaço. Mas funciona tudo perfeitamente, o problema está na hora de salvar dados com caracteres especiais, os registros que não tem especiais, salva normal!

Comment: Tentou `utf8_encode()`?

Comment: Tentei, e nada:

Comment: Com disse, tenta escapar os caracteres com a \, tipo \" \& \', pode acontecer desses caracteres estarem sendo interpretados de maneira errada.

Comment: Estes são os resultados: Regency Cafe </br> Specialty's Cafe & Bakery </br> Montague's Cafe </br> Freedom Cafe

Comment: Sendo que só mostra o 1° e o ultimo

Comment: Ótimo! Deu certo com "addslashes()"... Valeu Dunga Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução alternativa é que se estivermos utilizando **PDO**, o quarto parâmetro no momento de instanciar a classe PDO é super importante para situações de caracteres especiais.

```
//Fazemos a conexão com nosso banco de dados

$dsn = "mysql:dbname=nome_do_banco;host=localhost"; 
$dbuser = "root"; //usuário do banco
$dbpass = ""; //senha do banco
try
{
    //Instanciamos a classe PDO passando como parâmetro os dados de conexão pegos acima
     $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')); 
    //Esse quarto parâmetro é para corrigir problemas de acentuação

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{   
   //Se der erro na conexão, nós estourando esse Catch e é exibida essa mensagem junto com a mensagem do erro
   echo "A conexão falhou: ".$e->getMessage();
   exit;
}
```

**Esse é o parâmetro que me refiro:**

```
array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\'')
```

- Além, é claro, de termos que deixar os COLLATE e CHARSET do banco e das tabelas do banco de dados configurados da maneira correta.

Comment: ainda pode ser melhor:

`private const OPTIONS = [
        \PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8",
        \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
        \PDO::ATTR_CASE => \PDO::CASE_NATURAL
    ];`
E declara na instancia do PDO. resolve essa parte de acentuação etc

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que vi, é como o Dunga falou, pode estar ocorrento a quebra da string, tente escapar os caracteres especiais para inserir no banco:

```
$SQL = "INSERT INTO tb_detalhes_empresa 
           (place_id, nome_empresa, latitude, longitude, icone, scope, aberto_agora, reference, vicinity, harario_func_dias, foto_referencia, foto_height, foto_width, foto_atribuicoes, aberto_agora_periodos) 
       VALUES
           ('".mysqli_escape_string($serve, $e["place_id"])."', 
            '".mysqli_escape_string($serve, $name)."', 
            '".$_POST['latitude']."', 
            '".$_POST['longitude']."', 
            '".mysqli_escape_string($serve, $e["icon"]))."', 
            '', 
            '', 
            '".mysqli_escape_string($serve, $e["reference"]))."',               
            '".mysqli_escape_string($serve, $e["vicinity"]))."', 
            '', 
            '', 
            '', 
            '', 
            '', 
            '');";
```

Outro detalhe, pensando na segurança, seria interessante realizar uma filtragem um pouco maior das variáveis recebidas, usando filter_input ou filter_var.
Ainda na questão da segurança, eu recomendaria a utilização de Prepared Statements, o mysqli já tem suporte a isso.